# Open Loop Buck Converter - Regulating output voltage during rapid load change

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, load

I am designing an open loop buck converter. I want to limit the change in output voltage during rapid load change to a certain value. How should I modify my circuit design to achieve this goal?

Comment: By closing the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I should of specified. This is for a class and the circuit has to be open loop

Comment: @ShiconWen Slow down the system by making the inductor and capacitor ridiculously big.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Harry Svensson for providing a suitable solution.

To achieve the aforementioned goal, increase the inductor or capacitor size.

For my circuit, I only increased the capacitor size.

Comment: Heh, I was editing my comment thinking "hmm.. well the size of the inductor doesn't *really* matter since it's a buck converter, it's just storing energy. But it should theoretically make the system even slower since the LC oscillation frequency => \$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$ Hz".  - Hence why I kept the inductor part. But since it's not oscillating in that manner, it doesn't make sense, so I should've said to only increase the capacitor size. Nice that it worked out for you.